# C# Query string field in Azure Table Storage with Trim

Tags: c#, .net, azure, trim, azure-table-storage

I am trying to see if a user provided through an API exists in a table storage by checking for its username. The code looks similar to this:

```
public async Task<bool> UserExistsAsync(User user)
{
    var username = user.Username.Trim();
    var query = _usersTableClient.QueryAsync<UserEntity>(u => 
         u.Username.Trim().Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    await foreach (var page in query.AsPages())
    {
         if (page.Values.Any())
             return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, this code returns an error, as the **Trim()** method is not supported for querying Azure table storages:

> Method Trim not supported.

I need to somehow remove whitespaces, as the table is filled with values that contain whitesapces (e.g. **"  SomeUser"**). I do not have access to the table and I cannot ask the client to remove the whitespaces. Also loading all the entries in memory and checking them one by one (and eventually trimming them after being loaded) is not a solution, as the table has over 100k rows. Is there any workaround I can use to accomplish this?

Edit: tried with **Contains()**, **Substring()**, they are not allowed either.

Comment: It seems a bit obvious but is there a way of updating the user table to trim the username   as a one-off operation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a storage account in azure and use the connection use the connection string in the code.

[image]

Code in C# for trimming

```
        TableQuery<Customer> tableQuery = new TableQuery<Customer>();
        foreach (Customer customerEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storageConnectionString");
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            CloudTable tbl = tableClient.GetTableReference("tblCustomers");

            string name = customerEntity.CustomerName.Trim();

            TableOperation tblOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<Customer>("partitionKey", name);

            TableResult tr = tbl.Execute(tblOperation);

            if (tr.Result != null)
            {
                Customer user = (Customer)tr.Result;
                Console.WriteLine("User found: {0}", user.RowKey);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found: {0}", name);
            }
        }
```

For example, the below highlighted customer Name is having whitespace.

[image]

And this whitespace can be removed by using the below code.

```
foreach (Customer entity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            entity.CustomerName = entity.CustomerName.Replace(" ", "");
            table.Execute(TableOperation.Replace(entity));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking part of your time to write such a detailed answer! However, it is not really practical to load all the users and check them one by one locally (as the table is currently holding over 100k rows and it is expected to grow over time)...

Comment: yes, you do this by creating a batch file. And run this batch file in a scheduled time.

Comment: Converting the above code as Batch jobs or web jobs  will suffice.